# Retrieve URL Parameters Sent Through JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

I am not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or if I'm going about this the right way.  In some circumstances I want them to have a GET parameter as part of the URL.  I want the receiving page to be able to differentiate whether the sending load has a parameter or not and adjust accordingly.

Here is what I have that is sending the load:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                $("div.pageContent").html('');
                $("div.pageContent").load($(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            });
        });
```

In this case, the load could have "example.php" or "example.php?key=value".  In looking around (primarily on this site), I've found things that seem to be close, but don't quite get there.  In the page that is getting loaded (example.php), I have the following:

```
        function $_GET(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var URL = "example2.php";

            if ($_GET('key'))
            {
                URL = "example2.php?key=" + $_GET('key');
                URL = URL.split(' ').join('%20');
            }

            $("div.output").load(URL);
        });
```

If the sending source includes a query string, I want to add that to the URL and load it in a div that is unique to this page, otherwise I want to just load it as is without the query string.  The big issue I'm running into (I believe) is since this is coming from an AJAX call, the "window.location.href" is not what was sent from the JQuery but rather the URL of the root page which never changes.  Is there a way to be able to know what the full URL is that was sent from the load() in the first page by the second one?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the GET parameters were getting passed as I could access them through php without issue.  I didn't know that I could insert php code into a javascript block but once I tried it, all worked out.  My new code looks like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var URL = "example2.php";

            var myValue = "<?php echo $_GET['key']; ?>";

            if (myValue !== "")
            {
                URL = "example2.php?key=" + myValue;
                URL = URL.split(' ').join('%20');
            }

            $("div.output").load(URL);
        });
```

I was able to get rid of the GET function out of javascript entirely.  I probably made this much more difficult from the start but hopefully it can help someone else in the future.